# No more bronze badges being awarded on SO?

Tags: discussion, badges

For some time now, I've been noticing that, in the Recent Badges section of the right sidebar of stackoverflow.com, only silver badges are being shown.

Is it a bug, or do we have no more users earning bronze badges, leaving only the silver ones for more active users?

Comment: Is this still correct? I can see bronze badges on the home page. Unless home is not "stackoverflow.com" ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We stopped showing bronze *on the homepage* because they were so commonly awarded.

Only silver or better are shown.

This is only a display issue and has nothing to do with the badges themselves or how they are awarded.

Comment: Hah, I'd just finished writing the same answer, only I had to include a disclaimer about "informed speculation".

Comment: This was posted at the same time as my answer (which I'll now go and delete) & I was just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Which badges are you talking about, **all** bronze badges?

Here's a user who earned a bronze badge today
https://stackoverflow.com/users/132309/robbo

Comment: See Jeff's post. It's not that they aren't being awarded -- they just aren't being displayed on the homepage.

Comment: Not sure if that was directed at me or the OP, but I never said they weren't being awarded.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a while back that you don't get your bronze badge for nice answer (or related) if you happen to have a question that was previously given that badge and happened to fall below the limit.